# Usocket unsigned byte 8 doesn't receive data while character element type does

Tags: network-programming, common-lisp, usocket

I've run into some truly puzzling behavior with the USocket library. Consider the following snippet:

```
    (defvar server-socket (usocket:socket-listen "localhost" 43593 
                                                 :element-type 
                                                 '(unsigned-byte 8)))

    (defvar client-connection (usocket:socket-accept server-socket))
    ;in a separate terminal, type "telnet localhost 43593".
    ;then type some text and hit enter.

    (listen (usocket:socket-stream client-connection))
    => NIL
```

Why is this happening? When I leave out `:element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)` from the arguments to `usocket:socket-listen`, it works just fine. I could understand if any arbitrary bytes couldn't be represented as characters (utf-8 encoding for example has invalid sequences of bytes), but the inverse - characters that can't be represented by bytes - makes no sense, especially in a network context.

(I'm running clisp-2.49 on Lubuntu 15.10, USocket 0.6.3.2, in case that helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the precise wording used by the documentation for `listen` in the hyperspec (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listen.htm).

> Returns true if there is a ***character*** immediately available from input-stream; otherwise, returns false. On a non-interactive input-stream, listen returns true except when at end of file[1]. If an end of file is encountered, listen returns false. listen is intended to be used when input-stream obtains characters from an interactive device such as a keyboard.

Since the `socket-stream` doesn't produce characters if it's told to produce `'(unsigned-byte 8)`'s, `listen` will return `NIL` for the stream regardless of whether it has data ready to be read.

As far as I know, there is no alternative to `listen` for non-character types in the standard. Use usocket's `wait-for-input` instead, with `:timeout` set to 0 for polling (http://quickdocs.org/usocket/api).